# Getting exception in indexing data using node client

Tags: elasticsearch

I have used transport client before which works fine. I want to use node client now. I tried the following:

```
package es.code;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.node.Node;

import static org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class elasticsearch {

    private elasticsearch() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
        Client client = null;

        Node node = nodeBuilder().clusterName("sample_test").client(true).node();
        client = node.client();
        String json = "{" +
                "\"user\":\"prachi\"," +
                "\"postDate\":\"2013-01-30\"," +
                "\"message\":\"trying out Elasticsearch\"" +
                "}";

        IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("estest", "testing")
                .setSource(json)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();

        System.out.println(response.getId());    
        node.close();  
    }

}
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [1m]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$4.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeOperationAction.java:164)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:239)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(InternalClusterService.java:520)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**What is it which I am doing wrong? If I remove `client(true)`, the program runs successfully. But I don't see data in ES index.**

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I just played with your code and it works perfectly fine.For this code to work you must have your master node running on your cluster (with name sample_test). When you have client(true) ES will create a **Transport Client** instance which will remotely connect to the running cluster (not joining the cluster).

From node client documentation when client true

> Is the node going to be a client node which means it will hold no data
>   (node.data is set to false) and other optimizations by different
>   modules.

```
//Master node should be running. Works as a client. 
nodeBuilder().clusterName("sample_test").client(true).node() 

//Spin up individual node instance. 
nodeBuilder().clusterName("sample_test").node()
```

If you further need to configure data store for your node client following code might help you.

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("path.data", "D:\\ESDATA\\").build();
nodeBuilder().settings(settings);
Node node = nodeBuilder().clusterName("sample_test").data(true).settings(settings).node();
```